# How to determine the points of intersection between a 3d circle and polyhedron in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, geometry, intersection, polyhedra

I have a workspace containing a polyhedral shape so I sliced the workspace into different 3D circles. For each circle, it is either there occurs an intersection with the polyhedral or not. *Is it possible to determine if the circle intersects with the polyhedron in **MATLAB*** and if yes, **how can I determine the polygon formed by the intersection of a 3d circle with a polyhedral shape?**

NB: 3D circle is a circular shaped object in the 3D space. For ease of understanding, I have attached a MATLAB plot:

[image: 3D circle-polyhedral intersection]

There are 3 circles and four polyhedral shapes in the plot.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: By 3D circle you mean a [disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics))? As a first approach you could approximate the polyhedra with another shape like a sphere. Then it's easy to figure out if they intersect.

Comment: Yes, I have taught of this but the limitation is that some useful area of the workspace will be unduly reduced and this will affect motion freedom. Contrarily, please do you know of a general mathematical model that could be used to represent a (regular) polyhedral?